# Compiling CSV's dependent on Date

Tags: powershell

this is my first post so sorry about any mistakes.

I'm currently trying to use Powershell to combine folders of csv files based on date. I'm trying to go a week back, compile them, and export to another folder. I've only been using Powershell a few days and have an ok knowledge on coding in general.

I'm trying to use this fuction:

`(Get-ChildItem C:\Folder | Group-Object -AsHashTable  {$_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)})`

That outputs a name(true or false) and a value(folder title). What I want to do is use another function to then export those CSV files in several folders all to one folder.

Is this possible? Am I going in the right direction? I have very little experience with this.

Thanks.
Luke

Comment: So basically you want to copy all CSVs where `$_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)` to one folder ?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. Only the files that are true to that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to *filter by* instead of *group by*, hence you would be using [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2) instead of [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object). To copy files you can use the built-in cmdlet [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.2).

Do note, the `path\to\destinationfolder` in the example below **must be an existing folder**, you should create it before running the code.

```bash
# NOTE: If you want to filter only for files with .CSV Extension,
#       `-Filter *.csv` should be included
Get-ChildItem C:\Folder -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-2) } |
        Copy-Item -Destination path\to\destinationfolder
```

Comment: That makes sense. Although it's not working. I may be missing something.

Comment: @LukeShurtleff note that `$_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)` is filtering for Files which have been created after 2 days ago. Is that what you're looking for? If you remove `Copy-Item` and just filter, do you get any results? Also note I added `-Filter *.csv` to `Get-ChildItem` since you mentioned these were CSV files

Comment: Yes, that's correct. When I remove the filter, it places the folder, but none of the .csv files.

Comment: @LukeShurtleff Oh probably you need `-Recurse`, are the Csvs placed inside folders in the source folder?

Comment: Yes they're inside folders in the source folder. Removing the filter then added -Recurse at the end worked! Thanks a ton!